# Changing the value of a text element when the sky src is changed via a thumb link

Tags: aframe

As in a previous question I am trying to change the value of my a-text when I change the src of my a-sky via a thumb link. I have tried to create a separate click event to change it but that didn't work and I personally have very little experience in JavaScript and it confuses me. Im wondering iuf using the src image alts for the text to pull from is possible or if I have to do another method to have a different text value for each sky.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-template-component@3.x.x/dist/aframe-template-component.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-layout-component@4.x.x/dist/aframe-layout-component.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-event-set-component@5.x.x/dist/aframe-event-set-component.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-proxy-event-component@2.1.0/dist/aframe-proxy-event-component.min.jss"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        
    </header>
    <div class="container body-content-fix">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            <script id="link" type="text/html">
    <a-entity class="link"
      geometry="primitive: plane; height: 1; width: 1"
      material="shader: flat; src: ${thumb}"
      event-set__mouseenter="scale: 1.2 1.2 1"
      event-set__mouseleave="scale: 1 1 1"
      event-set__click="_target: #image-360; _delay: 300; material.src: ${src}"
      proxy-event="event: click; to: #image-360; as: fade"
      sound="on: click; src: #click-sound"></a-entity>
</script>

<a-scene embedded>
    <a-assets>
        <audio id="click-sound" src="https://cdn.aframe.io/360-image-gallery-boilerplate/audio/click.ogg"></audio>

        <!-- Images. -->
        <img id="goats" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/e18a8c9c-a862-434f-b8e2-1f40bd801c89/Goat360.jpg?v=1703804405761" alt="The goats have a dedicated pasture they roam about and a small barnhouse to stay in when weather gets rougher. They are fed hay when not grazing.">
        <img id="goats-thumb" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/e18a8c9c-a862-434f-b8e2-1f40bd801c89/goats-thumb.jpg?v=1703804405969">
        <img id="sheep" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/e18a8c9c-a862-434f-b8e2-1f40bd801c89/Sheep360.jpg?v=1703804411816" alt="">
        <img id="sheep-thumb" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/e18a8c9c-a862-434f-b8e2-1f40bd801c89/sheep-thumb.jpg?v=1703804386280">
        <img id="turkeys" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/e18a8c9c-a862-434f-b8e2-1f40bd801c89/Turkey360.jpg?v=1703804390053" alt="">
        <img id="turkeys-thumb" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/e18a8c9c-a862-434f-b8e2-1f40bd801c89/turkeys-thumb.jpg?v=1703804390304">
        <img id="chickens" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/e18a8c9c-a862-434f-b8e2-1f40bd801c89/Chicken360.jpg?v=1703804393290" alt="">
        <img id="chickens-thumb" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/e18a8c9c-a862-434f-b8e2-1f40bd801c89/chickens-thumb.jpg?v=1703804393554">
        <img id="cows" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/e18a8c9c-a862-434f-b8e2-1f40bd801c89/Cow360.jpg?v=1703804397500" alt="">
        <img id="cows-thumb" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/e18a8c9c-a862-434f-b8e2-1f40bd801c89/cows-thumb.jpg?v=1703804397660">
        <img id="pigs" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/e18a8c9c-a862-434f-b8e2-1f40bd801c89/Pig360.jpg?v=1703804408933" alt="">
        <img id="pigs-thumb" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/e18a8c9c-a862-434f-b8e2-1f40bd801c89/pigs-thumb.jpg?v=1703804409101">
        <img id="geese" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/e18a8c9c-a862-434f-b8e2-1f40bd801c89/Geese360.jpg?v=1703804401918" alt="">
        <img id="geese-thumb" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/e18a8c9c-a862-434f-b8e2-1f40bd801c89/geese-thumb.jpg?v=1703804403383">
        
    </a-assets>

    <!-- 360-degree image. -->
    <a-sky id="image-360" radius="10" src="#goats"></a-sky>

    <!-- Link template we will build. -->
    <a-entity id="links" layout="type: line; margin: 1.5" position="-4.5 -1.5 -4">
        <a-entity template="src: #link" data-src="#goats" data-thumb="#goats-thumb"></a-entity>
        <a-entity template="src: #link" data-src="#sheep" data-thumb="#sheep-thumb"></a-entity>
        <a-entity template="src: #link" data-src="#turkeys" data-thumb="#turkeys-thumb"></a-entity>
        <a-entity template="src: #link" data-src="#chickens" data-thumb="#chickens-thumb"></a-entity>
        <a-entity template="src: #link" data-src="#cows" data-thumb="#cows-thumb"></a-entity>
        <a-entity template="src: #link" data-src="#pigs" data-thumb="#pigs-thumb"></a-entity>
        <a-entity template="src: #link" data-src="#geese" data-thumb="#geese-thumb"></a-entity>
    </a-entity>

    <a-text id="descriptor" value="The goats have a dedicated pasture they roam about and a small barnhouse to stay in when weather gets rougher. They are fed hay when not grazing." font="mozillavr"  negate="false" scale="1 1 1" position="-3 2 -4"></a-text>
    <!-- Camera + Cursor. -->
    <a-camera>
        <a-cursor id="cursor"
                  animation__click="property: scale; from: 0.1 0.1 0.1; to: 1 1 1; easing: easeInCubic; dur: 150; startEvents: click"
                  animation__clickreset="property: scale; to: 0.1 0.1 0.1; dur: 1; startEvents: animationcomplete__click"
                  animation__fusing="property: scale; from: 1 1 1; to: 0.1 0.1 0.1; easing: easeInCubic; dur: 150; startEvents: fusing"></a-cursor>
    </a-camera>
</a-scene>
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="">
        
    </footer>

   
    <script src="script.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Refer to https://glitch.com/edit/#!/alabaster-zigzag-egret to see full code.